# looping through an array of objects that contains three key, value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

I have these objects, which could be in an array, like in the example or a database:

```
[  
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": 1000, "timestamp": "2020-11-02T14:00:00Z" }
  { "payer": "UNILEVER", "points": 200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T11:00:00Z" } 
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": -200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T15:00:00Z" } 
  { "payer": "MILLER COORS", "points": 10000, "timestamp": "2020-11-01T14:00:00Z" } 
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": 300, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T10:00:00Z" }
]
```

I want to subtract a total of `{ "points": 5000 }` as an example from the points values of these objects starting with the oldest points based on timestamp, keep in mind no payer's points to go negative. then I want to return how much each payer's points were used. The expected result looks like this:

```
[
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": -100 },
  { "payer": "UNILEVER", "points": -200 },
  { "payer": "MILLER COORS", "points": -4,700 }
]
```

My initial solution was:

1. To sort the array based on the oldest timestamp
2. Create a new object to store the number of points used from each payer
3. Looping through the sorted array and subtracting the points from each payer and
   storing the number of points used in that new object.
4. push all new objects to an array and return it.
   This solution made sense to me but I couldn't implement it, I kept on having unexpected results until my brain froze and I can't think anymore.

This is an apprenticeship interview question. I thought it was easy at the beginning, but then after spending hours without solving it, I'm thinking am I an imposter? or is this question a tricky one?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and experience and helping me out. I appreciate it!

Comment: What is the programming language? And can you share your code attempt and indicate where it gave "unexpected results"?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript,
```
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.timestamp - b.timestamp
  })
```
The sorting function is not sorting the array, it remains unchanged even when I try to reverse the order nothing change

Comment: That's why you need to add your code to your question, because there is a problem there: `timestamp` is not a number, so subtracting is not going to have the effect you want.

Comment: Also, how do you decide how many points to subtract? Why in the example you have for MILLER -100 in the expected result, and not -200 or -300?

Comment: I know the timestamp is not a number, I found an answer on StackOverflow that says to change the timestamp to date like this `array.sort(a, b) => { return Date(a.timestamp) - Date(b.timestamp)}` but still didn't work. I apologize that I don't have a code to include in the question.

In the expected output DANNON -100 because when you go through the array by timestamp, you take the oldest one DANNON 300 then go to the next step by timestamp which Is UNILEVER 200 then the next step DANNON -200 and that's how only -100 was left from DANNON and the final step was MILLER COORS -4700

Comment: I still don't understand why there's no code despite you worked on it for hours and the question is barely understandable. Actually there are lots of doubts triggering anyone reading it. I really think you should begin with being more clear, doing examples that make sense, and possibly just show input and output expectations. If you give suggestions on how you would implement the solution to a problem, you should also include your attempt so it will be easier to spot the exact issue in your code

Comment: @ Diego De Vita I worked on it for hours without advancing so I was deleting the code and starting over and I don't have any code to show now. The question is part of a coding assessment exercise for a backend apprenticeship role. the examples I shared are the examples given to me by them! so this is what I had to work with!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it took me a while to understand what you meant.. then finally it made sense. I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented those steps you listed in your questions and made a function `subtract(payers, subtractingPoints)`:

that given an array of payers and a number of points to substract, it will sort the array by timestamp and will take away those points from each payer until that number is reached or array length has been hit before all the points could be substracted.

The function returns an array of objects each one saying how much points were taken by each single payer (grouped).

```js
let payers = [  
  {
    "payer": "DANNON",
    "points": 1000,
    "timestamp": "2020-11-02T14:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "payer": "UNILEVER",
    "points": 200,
    "timestamp": "2020-10-31T11:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "payer": "DANNON",
    "points": -200,
    "timestamp": "2020-10-31T15:00:00Z"
  }, 
  {
    "payer": "MILLER COORS",
    "points": 10000,
    "timestamp": "2020-11-01T14:00:00Z"
  }, 
  {
    "payer": "DANNON",
    "points": 300,
    "timestamp": "2020-10-31T10:00:00Z"
  }
];

const o = subtract(payers, 5000);
console.log(o);

function subtract(payers, subtractingPoints){

  payers.sort(function(x, y){
    date1 = new Date(x.timestamp);
    date2 = new Date(y.timestamp);
    return date1 - date2 ;
  });
  
  payersAccounted = {};
  let i = 0;
  while(subtractingPoints > 0 && i < payers.length){
    
    const currentPayer = payers[i].payer;
    
    let pointsTookAway =
      Math.min(payers[i].points, subtractingPoints);
    
    if( !(currentPayer in payersAccounted) )
      payersAccounted[currentPayer] = pointsTookAway;
    else
      payersAccounted[currentPayer] += pointsTookAway;
      
    subtractingPoints -= pointsTookAway;
    i++;
  }
  
  let result = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(payersAccounted)) {
    result.push( { "payer": key, "points": -1*value } );
  }
  
  return result;
}
```